# Java вывод символов на консоль по "координатам"

Tags: java, вывод, ввод, символы, координаты

Есть программа:

```
Scanner Low = new 
Scanner(System.in);

  int one = 2, two = 4, free = 6, one1, sup;

for (sup = 0; sup < 1; sup--) {
  one1 = Low.nextInt();

  
  if (one1 == one){
    System.out.println("|");}
    
  else if (one1 == two) {
    System.out.println ("<-");}
  
  else if (one1 == free) {
    System.out.println ("->");
  }
  else{
    sup--;
  }
}
```

Сейчас если ввести 2624 будет:

```
|
->
|
<-
```

Как мне сделать чтобы оно поварачивало, относительно прошлого символа, например 2624:

```
|
 ->
   |
 <-
```

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Ну по всей видимости в твоей задаче нужно запоминать движение вправо/влево, и выводить нужное количество пробелов перед тем как писать палочку или стрелочку.

Но из задачи не совсем понятно что конкретно нужно

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner Low = new
                Scanner(System.in);

        int one = 2, two = 4, free = 6, one1, sup, dist = 0;

        for (sup = 0; sup < 1; sup--) {
            one1 = Low.nextInt();


            if (one1 == one) {
                printdist(dist);
                System.out.println("|");
            } else if (one1 == two) {
                printdist(dist);
                System.out.println("<-");
                dist--;
            } else if (one1 == free) {
                printdist(dist);
                System.out.println("->");
                dist++;
            } else {
                sup--;
            }
        }
    }

    static void printdist(int dist) {
        for (int i = 0; i < dist; i++)
            System.out.print(" ");
    }
}
```

Comment: ну значит я правильно понял. тебе нужно запоминать дистанцию от борта в какой-то переменной. и если дистанция 2, то перед тем как выводить палочку или стрелочку ты должен вывести 2 пробела. ну и соответственно когда делаешь движение вправо, то увеличиваешь значение дистанции в переменной на 1, а когда влево то уменьшаешь значение на 1. вот и все

Comment: Нужно чтобы символ изменял направление учитывая нахождения символа до него.

Comment: попробуй как в примере. это если я правильно понял задачу :)

Comment: помогло решение?

Comment: Да помогло, разобрался, огромное спасибо. Начал потихоньку учить джава неделю назад, только сейчас узнал о команде print)

Comment: Вроде на этом сайте есть понятие благодарности, а команды print в java нет ;)